# Como extraer cada elemento del array y realizar un insert independiente por cada uno

Tags: php, mysqli, checkbox, foreach

Se requiere separar los valores de una array en filas independientes para poder insertar cada fila por separa en una base de datos.

La idea es guardar en BD varios checks al mismo tiempo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código para el INSERT

```html
foreach ($check_N2 = $_POST['check_N2'] as $val_N2) {


    $empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
    $id_empresa = implode(" ", $empresa);
    $fecha_registro = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) as cont FROM respuestas");

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $cont = $row['cont'] + 1; // incrementa   
        $num = sprintf("%'.02d", $cont); // formato con 5 digitos
        $codigo = "RES" . "-" . $num; // se concatena con el año actual
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO respuestas (id_empresa, codigo, nombre, fecha_registro) VALUES (\"$id_empresa\",\"$codigo\", \"$$val_N2\", \"$fecha_registro\")";

}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema o error? ¿Hiciste un `echo $sql;` para verificar lo que se está intentando insertar? ¿Por qué creas un incremento para `id_empresa`, acaso esa columna no es autoincrement en la tabla? ¿Por qué sacas una y otra vez el dato `$empresa` dentro del bucle si es siempre el mismo que hay en `$_POST`?

Comment: gracias ya solucionado, aplique mucho de lo que comenta, muchas gracias por su respuesta y tiempo